# How can I send a user's coordinates from phonegap to a remote server/mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cordova

Specifically gps coordinates?

Basically the user will be able to view the location of other users on a google map. So I need to figure out how to send the users coordinates to my express app. Once they are stored in a mongodb, all of the coordinates can be rendered on a user's google map.

The basic question is: How can I take the user's coordinates from phonegap and store them in a remote server/mongodb?

I think an XMLHttpRequest Post request will send the relevant data, but how can I set up my server so that it receives that data and stores it using mongoose?

Always appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your title.  Is that the actual question you are asking?

Comment: No that's not my question. The question should be closer to: How can I send a user's coordinates from phonegap to a remote server/mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather broad. But i'll try to point you in the right direction.

**1. Read the phonegap api-docs on geolocation**
Here you will find out how to `getCurrentPosition` and extract other useful data from the client.
[Phonegap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_geolocation_geolocation.md.html)

**2. Send data to your server**
With plain JavaScript, zizzle.js, jQuery or any other framework you like you set up a `post request` to the server with the data.
[jQuery Docs: examples using jQuery.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

**3. Recieve data**
I don't know what server framework your using, but if you haven't decided yet, go with [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org/). A great framework for CRUD ops / rest-api.

- [Set up a model for your coordinates](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/models)
- [Set up a simple controller in sails](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers)

**4. Store data in MongoDb**
Using Sails.js its very easy to persist data in any source you like. Set ut the config for your mongodb, and read the docs on sailsjs.

Here is a simple `create` using sails example:

```
 // For example
User.create({
  name: 'Mike',
  age: 13,
  phoneNumber: '(512)-555-5555'
}).done(function(err, user) {

  // Error handling
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);

  // The User was created successfully!
  } else {
    console.log("User created:", user);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is really comprehensive. I think I was too general in my original question though. I narrowed it down here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23088635/how-do-i-send-data-from-phonegap-to-an-express-app Please take a look if you have a chance. Thanks!