# How do I send data from phonegap to an express app?

Tags: cordova, express

I'm trying to make an ajax post request inside of phonegap, and then receive that data inside of an express app. This is what my code looks like:

Phonegap:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:"http://localhost:3000/test",
        data: {'test':'test'},
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        crossDomain: true,
        success: function(data){
            console.log('data successfully sent');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('there was an error');
        }
    });
```

Express:

```
    app.get('/test' , function (req , res){
  console.log(req.body);
  res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Inside of my express console I am seeing an empty object. Inside the phonegap console it is logging an error.

Does anybody know what I'm missing here? Is this even the right direction for being able to send data from phonegap to express? I want to eventually store the data inside of a mongodb once it hits the express app.

Please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the access=* permissions?

Comment: `localhost` is not a valid domain for the mobile device, use the IP address instead

Comment: @Renalf: I'm not sure what you mean. Where do I include this? Dawson: Does that mean I need to have my express app hosted before it can receive data? Both the phonegap app (ripple) and express app (localhost) are being run on my machine.

Comment: The IP address did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `dataType: 'jsonp'` with `dataType: 'json',` your ajax call will not fire with `jsonp`

Comment: This is not a fix. Also, from what I've read on stackoverflow jsonp is necessary for cross-domain requests.